# Clear Source Sheets Formatting before Merging Data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a code that successfully merges data from a specific named sheets of multiple workbooks into specific master workbook sheet.

However, the code merges empty rows too that have **some sort of formatting** in them. In my case, the source sheets have boderlines without any values in the empty rows. I tried using `SourceRange.Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells)).ClearFormats`  but it fails to resolve the problem.

If I manually clear the formatting from the source files, **save the file** and then run the code it works right. But that's not possible in real time scenario.

A novice to VBA. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

My Files are shared in G Drive: [Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11XE...ew?usp=sharing)

Note: RDM_Last is a Function used to determine the last row/cell with value. I have added the code below the main code.

The Code:

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks2()
Dim FirstCell As String
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim myFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
MyPath = "C:\Users\zatin.dharmapuri\Desktop\3. 2018\Raw Data Month wise\Jan-2018"

' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
' in the search folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve myFiles(1 To FNum)
    myFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

' Set various application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' The sheet name for the data to be copied to.
Set BaseWks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
rnum = 2

' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(myFiles) To UBound(myFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & myFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next

            'Change this range to fit your own needs.
            'With mybook.Worksheets("Defect Analysis Reports")
               'Set sourceRange = .Range("A5:J104")
            'End With

        With mybook.Worksheets("Defect Analysis Reports")
            FirstCell = "A5"
            Set sourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells))
            .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells)).ClearFormats
            'Test if the row of the last cell >= then the row of the FirstCell
            If RDB_Last(1, .Cells) < .Range(FirstCell).Row Then
                Set sourceRange = Nothing

            End If
        End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                ' If source range uses all columns then
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Copy the file name in column A.
                    With sourceRange
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = myFiles(FNum)
                    End With

                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                    Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next FNum
    'BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If
       ExitTheSub:
       'Restore the application properties.
     With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

MsgBox "All Data has been merged successfully"
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

RDM_Last Function Code:

```
Function RDB_Last(choice As Integer, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
Dim lrw As Long
Dim lcol As Integer

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        after:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        RDB_Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            RDB_Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: What is `RDB_Last`?

Comment: RDB_Last is a function used to identify the last row with value. I got this function from the following URL: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

The RDM_Last function is found at the very end.

Comment: Can you add the code to your question please? Check what address the function is returning.

Comment: Ok, I have added the RDM_Last code in my question as EDIT. I don't understand your second part of question. Sorry about it.

Comment: What is the value of `RDB_Last` for one of the sheets when it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, This got resolved and it was a silly miss. It's not formatting that is the issue. Several of the files have latent data in cells BI520:CU531. That's messed up the LastCell calculation.

Credit goes to AlfaFrog from
https://www.excelforum.com/members/235459.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells)).ClearFormats` instead of `Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells)).ClearFormats`.

If you want to refer to range within certain sheet while using `With` you should refer to ranges using dot before range i.e. `.Range`. Currently your range may refer to some other sheet.

Comment: Hi Tom,
I tried your suggestion but it does not work. I updated the code in the question with a dot before Range. What I noticed was, the code is currently coping 527 rows of every sheet with the exception of the first file (CNS_...) as I cleared the formatting in that sheet manually for testing purposes.

Comment: Please don't edit your code in your question. This would make your question harder to answer by other people.

Comment: Sure, I'll remember that.

Comment: I would advise to put breakpoint at `Set sourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells))` and put `sourceRange.Select` after it to see if for first file you are actually have non empty sourceRange. Maybe for the first file sourceRange becomes nothing for some reason?

Comment: Ok, after doing what you suggested, the first file opens up and cell C105 is set as active cell. But the last row with data is at 70

Comment: Ok,
 This got resolved and it was a silly miss. It's not formatting that is the issue. Several of the files have latent data in cells BI520:CU531. That's messed up the LastCell calculation.

Credit goes to AlfaFrog from
https://www.excelforum.com/members/235459.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
This got resolved and it was a silly miss. It's not formatting that is the issue. Several of the files have latent data in cells BI520:CU531. That's messed up the LastCell calculation.

Credit goes to AlfaFrog from
https://www.excelforum.com/members/235459.html

Thanks for the time experts.